# jquery- popup closes immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

On an html page, I'm having a hyperlink(id='WhatsNew'), which on clicking displays an html page as a poup, using the following jquery code:

```
$jQ(document).ready(function(){
var pars="WhatsNew=Y";
   $jQ.post("/Bids/whatsnew",pars,function(result){
       if(result=="no"){
        return false;   
       }else{
           var bsdPFA= BootstrapDialog.show({
             title:'What\'s New?',
             message:result, nl2br:false, 
             draggable:true, 
             buttons:[{label:'Close', id: 'wn_close',
             action:function(dialogRef){
                 dialogRef.close();
                }
             }]
          });
           bsdPFA.$modal.find('.modal-dialog').css({'width':'60%','height':'auto'});
       }
   });
```

In another file, I'm having the jquery code which handles the click:

```
if ($('WhatsNew')) {
    Event.observe('WhatsNew', 'click', function(){
            var myAjax = new Ajax.Request('/bids/whatsnew/', {method: 'post', onComplete:showDropBox});
//window.open("/bids/whatsnew/", 'Help', "height=300,width=600,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes", true);
          //window.open("/bids/whatsnew/","mywindow","scrollbars=1,width="+screen.availWidth.toString()+",height="+screen.availHeight.toString());
            });
}
```

My code for 'showDropBox' function:

```
var user_data = response.responseText.split('::');
var email = user_data[0];
var name = user_data[1];

if (typeof(Zenbox) !== "undefined") {
    Zenbox.init({
        //dropboxID:   "20015556",
        dropboxID:   "20020983",
        url:         "https://hotelrfp.zendesk.com",
        tabID:       "support",
        tabColor:    "black",
        tabPosition: "Left",
        hide_tab: true,
        requester_name: name,
        requester_email: email
    });
```

Whenever I click on the hyperlink, pop-up opens for a very small duration(almost half of a second) and closes. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: What have you written in on complete 'ShowDriobox' function? that may contains the code for closing the popup.. please check

Comment: Please check to make sure that you have either *bootstrap.js* OR *bootstrap-modal.js*, but not both.can you post a jsfiddle

Comment: @SreerejithSS I have edited the question to include the code for 'showDropBox'. Please have a look....